# Assign statement and overflow check

Tags: c, kvm

I got one question when looking into KVM-QEMU source codes.

```
ram_size = sz;
if (ram_size != sz) {
    fprintf(stderr, "qemu: ram size too large\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

sz is `uint64_t` and ram_size is `ram_addr_t`, which is also defined as `uint64_t`.

What are the above codes used for (check integer overflow)? How does it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you look closer at the definition of `ram_addr_t`, you'll see something like:

```
/* address in the RAM (different from a physical address) */
#if defined(CONFIG_XEN_BACKEND)
typedef uint64_t ram_addr_t;
#  define RAM_ADDR_MAX UINT64_MAX
#  define RAM_ADDR_FMT "%" PRIx64
#else
typedef uintptr_t ram_addr_t;
#  define RAM_ADDR_MAX UINTPTR_MAX
#  define RAM_ADDR_FMT "%" PRIxPTR
#endif
```

Note that it might also be a `uintptr_t`, which might not be a 64-bit type.  In that case, there'd be a problem with that assignment if `sz` were greater than `UINTPTR_MAX`.